# Disable HttpClient Wire Logging

Tags: java, log4j, httpclient

I would like to disable **Wire** class debug information, I have the following **log4j.properties** file

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, console, file

log4j.org.apache.http.wire=ERROR

log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c: %L - %m%n

log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=LogFile.log
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.conversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c: %L - %m%n
```

I have **slf4j, log4j and commons logging** jars in my class path.